# What are the most common reasons for not being able to edit UVs?

Tags: uv

In 2.80

I have unwrapped the UVs. But I can't edit them now. 
I tested this with another object in a different file and that was not a problem, so I guess it's something specific to my other file.
Also, the UVs only show while I have them all selected in the 3D view. Is there a way to have them all showing whether they're selected or not?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share your file and add more information?

Comment: *"Is there a way to have them all showing whether they're selected or not"* I suppose the same as in 2.79, either select mesh in Edit mode or enable sync. That aside, make sure you have UV editor opened, not Image editor which are not the same in 2.8

Answer (score -1):

Strangely, the solution was to remove the texture I had on that mesh.